# Repaint not being called

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm making a simple maze solving algorithm (A* but that's not pertinent) and a GUI to display the agent navigating through the maze. I have a MapModel class that deals with the state and a MapView class that draws everything to a JPanel. I have the MapModel class call repaint everytime the state changes, but when I need my unit to animate (in the moveAgent() method), repaint isn't getting called. I've debugged the program and the repaint method is being reached every "frame" but MapView's paintComponent method isn't being called.

I'm relatively new to UI and animation, I haven't coded much else other than scripts and C programs, so I might be doing this completely wrong. Let me know if I should redesign any of my classes to fit better with standard java swing practices!

Here's my code. There are other classes, but I'm quite sure they're unrelated to the problem. I can post them as well if you'd like.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that repaint does work sometimes, just not in moveAgent(). When I call it from createRandomObstacles(), it paints correctly.

MapModel.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MapModel {
    int width, height, start_diameter, speed;
    ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacle_list = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();
    Agent agent;
    GridSpaceManager grid_manager;
    String current_algorithm = "NONE";
    ArrayList<Point> subgoal_list;
    MapView map_view;
    boolean animate = false;
    AnimationManager animation_manager = new AnimationManager();

    public MapModel(int size, MapView map_view)
    {
        this.width = size;
        this.height = size;
        this.map_view = map_view;
    }

    public void updateMapModel (){
        map_view.repaint();
    }
    //if obstacles can't fit then method returns
    public void createRandomObstacles(int num_obstacles, int start_diameter)
    {
        this.start_diameter = start_diameter;
        obstacle_list.clear();
        ArrayList<Point> point_list = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for(int i = 0; i < num_obstacles; i++) {
            int rand_x = (int)(Math.random()*(width-start_diameter))+start_diameter;
            int rand_y = (int)(Math.random()*(height-start_diameter))+start_diameter;
            point_list.add(new Point(rand_x, rand_y));

        }


        for(int i = 0; i < num_obstacles; i++) {


            double min_distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            Point p1 = point_list.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < num_obstacles; j++) {
                Point p2 = point_list.get(j);
                if(j != i && p1.distance(p2) < min_distance)
                    min_distance = p1.distance(p2);
            }
            min_distance = Math.sqrt(min_distance*min_distance/2);
            int min_int = (int)(min_distance/2);
            if(min_int > 1) {
                int width = (int)(Math.random()*(min_int)); 
                width = Math.min(width, Math.max(p1.x, this.width - p1.x));
                int height = (int)(Math.random()*(min_int));
                height = Math.min(height, Math.max(p1.y, this.height - p1.y));
                if(p1.x + width > this.width - start_diameter && p1.y + height > this.height - start_diameter) {
                    width = this.width - start_diameter - p1.x; 
                    height = this.height - start_diameter - p1.y;
                }

                if(!(width < 0 && height < 0))
                    obstacle_list.add(new Obstacle(p1.x, p1.y, width, height));
            }
        }

        updateMapModel();
    }

    public void moveAgent() {
        if(animation_manager.running) {
            animation_manager.act();

            double speed = Math.sqrt(width*height/10);
            Point p = subgoal_list.get(0);
            if(p.x == agent.x && p.y == agent.y) {
                if(subgoal_list.size() == 1) {
                    animate = false;
                    return;
                }
                subgoal_list.remove(0);
                p = subgoal_list.get(0);
            }

            double distance = Point.distance(agent.x, agent.y, p.x, p.y);
            double delta_x = (p.x - agent.x)/distance;
            double delta_y = (p.y - agent.y)/distance;
            double distance2 = Math.sqrt(delta_x*delta_x + delta_y+delta_y);
            if(distance2 > distance) {
                agent.x = p.x;
                agent.y = p.y;
            }
            else {
                agent.x += delta_x;
                agent.y += delta_y;
            }
            long sleep_time = animation_manager.timeTillNextFrame();
            if(sleep_time > 0)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep_time);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {

                }
            updateMapModel();
            moveAgent();
        }
        else {
            endPathfinding();
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation(int agent_diameter, boolean animate) {
        agent = new Agent(0,0,agent_diameter);
        this.animate = animate;

        animation_manager.start();
        moveAgent();
    }

    public void startPathfinding(String algorithm, int agent_diameter, boolean animate) {

        if(algorithm.equals("A*")) {
            startAStar(agent_diameter);
            this.current_algorithm = "A*";
        }
        if(subgoal_list == null) {
            this.current_algorithm = "NONE";
        }
        startAnimation(agent_diameter, animate);
    }

    public void endPathfinding() {
        agent = null;
        subgoal_list = null;
        animation_manager.end();
        this.current_algorithm = "NONE";
    }

    public void startAStar(int agent_diameter) {
        grid_manager = new GridSpaceManager(obstacle_list, width, height);
        if(agent_diameter > start_diameter) return;
        agent = new Agent(agent_diameter/2, agent_diameter/2, agent_diameter);
        subgoal_list = AStar(grid_manager.getNode(0, 0), grid_manager.getNode(width - 1, height - 1));
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> AStar(SearchSpaceNode start, SearchSpaceNode goal) {
        Point start_point = start.point_list[0];
        Point goal_point = goal.point_list[0];
        PriorityQueue<SearchSpaceNode> open_set = new PriorityQueue<SearchSpaceNode>();
        ArrayList<SearchSpaceNode> closed_set = new ArrayList<SearchSpaceNode>();

        HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, SearchSpaceNode> came_from = new HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, SearchSpaceNode>();
        HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer> g_score = new HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer>();
        HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer> f_score = new HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer>();

        int start_f_value = (int)manhattan_distance(start,goal);

        g_score.put(start, 0);
        f_score.put(start, start_f_value);

        start.f_value = start_f_value;
        open_set.add(start);

        while(open_set.size() > 0) {
            SearchSpaceNode current = open_set.poll();


            if(current == goal) {
                ArrayList<Point> subgoal_list = reconstructPath(came_from, current);
                subgoal_list.add(goal_point);
                return subgoal_list;
            }

            closed_set.add(current);
            ArrayList<SearchSpaceNode> neighbors = current.getNeighbors();
            for(int i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); i++) {
                SearchSpaceNode neighbor = neighbors.get(i);
                if(closed_set.contains(neighbor))
                    continue;

                int tentative_g_score = g_score.get(current) + 1;

                if(!open_set.contains(neighbor) || !g_score.containsKey(neighbor) 
                        || tentative_g_score < g_score.get(neighbor)) {
                    int tentative_f_score = tentative_g_score + (int)manhattan_distance(neighbor, goal);

                    came_from.put(neighbor, current);
                    g_score.put(neighbor, tentative_g_score);
                    f_score.put(neighbor, tentative_f_score);
                    neighbor.f_value = tentative_f_score;
                    if(!open_set.contains(neighbor))
                        open_set.add(neighbor);
                }

            }
        }



        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> reconstructPath(
            HashMap<SearchSpaceNode,SearchSpaceNode> came_from,SearchSpaceNode current_node) {
        ArrayList<Point> subgoal_list = new ArrayList<Point>();


        while(came_from.containsKey(current_node)) {
            SearchSpaceNode temp = came_from.get(current_node); 
            subgoal_list.add(0, temp.point_list[0]);
            came_from.remove(current_node);
            current_node = temp;
        }
        return subgoal_list;
    }

    public double manhattan_distance(SearchSpaceNode start, SearchSpaceNode goal) {
        Point start_point = start.point_list[0];
        Point goal_point = goal.point_list[0];
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(goal_point.x - start_point.x,2) + Math.pow(goal_point.x - start_point.x,2));
        //return Math.abs(goal_point.x - start_point.x) + Math.abs(goal_point.y - start_point.y);
    }

    public String algorithmRunning(){return current_algorithm;}
}

class AnimationManager {
    boolean running = false;
    int frame_number = -1;
    int milliseconds_per_frame = 500;
    long start_time = -1;


    public void start() {
        running  = true;
        start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        frame_number = 0;
    }

    public void end() {
        running = false;
        start_time = frame_number = -1;
    }

    public void act() {
        frame_number++;
    }
    public long timeTillNextFrame() {
        return  (frame_number + 1)*milliseconds_per_frame - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);
    }
}
```

MapView.java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapView extends JPanel{

    private int size, actual_map_size;
    MapModel map_model;
    Point current_subgoal = null;

    int frame_number = 0;
    long start_time;
    public MapView(int size)
    {
        this.setBounds(0,200,600,600);

        this.size = size;
    }
    boolean starting_print = true;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int x_offset = 10, y_offset = 10;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect((600-size)/2 + x_offset - 2, y_offset - 2,size + 5, size + 5);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect((600-size)/2 + x_offset - 1, y_offset - 1,size+3,size+3);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        if(this.map_model != null) {
            ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacle_list = map_model.obstacle_list;
            for(int i = 0; i < obstacle_list.size(); i++) {
                Obstacle o = obstacle_list.get(i);
                g.fillRect(scaleX(o.x) + x_offset,scale(o.y) + y_offset,
                        scale(o.width),scale(o.height));
            }

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            if(map_model.current_algorithm.equals("A*")) {
                GridSpaceManager grid = map_model.grid_manager;

                for(int i = 0; i < map_model.width; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j< map_model.height; j++) {
                        SearchSpaceNode node = grid.getNode(i, j);
                        if(node != null) {
                            Point p = node.point_list[0];
                            g.drawRect(scaleX(p.x) + x_offset, scale(p.y) + y_offset, scale(1), scale(1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Agent agent = map_model.agent;


            if(agent != null) {
                g.fillOval(scaleX(agent.x) + x_offset, scale(agent.y) + y_offset,
                        Math.max(2,scale(agent.diameter)), Math.max(2,scale(agent.diameter)));
            }

        }

    }

    private int scaleX(int x) {
        double scale = ((double)size) / ((double)actual_map_size);
        return (int)(((double)x)*scale)+(600-size)/2;
    }
    private int scale(int val) {
        double scale = ((double)size) / ((double)actual_map_size);
        return (int)(((double)val)*scale);
    }

    public void setMapModel(MapModel map) {
        this.map_model = map;
    }

    public void setMapScale(int actual_map_size) {
        this.actual_map_size = actual_map_size;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO The model shouldn't be interacting with the view in any way.  The model should be divorced from the view.  It should provide event notification when something changes, but beyond that, it shouldn't care whose listening...

Comment: How is your animation driven?  Why do your `moveAgent` method call itself repeatedly?  This should be driven from another process/main loop, which controls the speed of the updates.  From all indications, I would guess that you are blocking the EDT

Comment: While I'm at it `this.setBounds(0,200,600,600);` looks suspicious...

Comment: I wasn't sure how I should go about animations. I made the "mainloop" moveAgent because that is the only "animation" that occurs. How would you suggest I do animation? I have no idea what an EDT is, could you elaborate? You're right about the model being divorced, that's very messy of me. Shoudl the notification provide information about the state of the model (IE what it should paint)? I couldn't figure out an elegant way to have the information communicated to MapView without a reference to MapModel

Comment: About the this.setBounds(0,200,600,600), I'm just setting everything absolutely right now. I wasn't sure about the way to go about setting sizes as I don't deal with UI much. I'm making this for my thesis, and I'm just in a hurry to get to actually implementing my algorithms but I guess I'm cutting too many corners :( Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: "EDT" is short for [Event Dispatching Thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Notifications depend. If the only thing that the model wants to tell the outside world is the fact that it's state has changed, then I might use a `ChangeListener` and let each listener figure out what that means. If you want to know more detailed information, I would construct a listener of my own, with the events I think people might be interested in, ie `contentsChanged` when the maze changes, `agentMoved` when the agent changes location.

Comment: Animation can be achieved in a number of ways, but you need to make sure you're not blocking the EDT, otherwise paints won't occur.  Something like a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) is really good for simple animations and it's `tick` events occur within the EDT, making it safe for updating the UI. As with the `setBounds`, so long as the container it's in is using a `null` layout you should be fine, I was concerned that a layout manager might have been hiding it

Comment: I'm using null layout so that's fine. I'm only going to be enabling the animations for relatively small maps (100x100 max) so I shouldn't be sending to much state through notifications. I guess I can just send the entire object list, statespace representation and agent location. 

I'll implement the Timer change first, hopefully that fixes the repaint() problem. I'll work on making my model more independent from the view and implementing notifications tomorrow. That Timer class looks quite useful!

Comment: Love Swing `Timer`, very useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

I redesigned my code to use the Timer class at the suggestion of MadProgrammer. It was a much neater way to get my animations working! Here's the new code below. The MapView class remains unchanged.

MapModel.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MapModel implements ActionListener{
    boolean running = false;
    int milliseconds_per_frame = 500;
    Timer timer = new Timer(milliseconds_per_frame, this);

    int width, height, start_diameter, speed;
    ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacle_list = new ArrayList<Obstacle>();
    Agent agent;
    GridSpaceManager grid_manager;
    String current_algorithm = "NONE";
    ArrayList<Point> subgoal_list;
    MapView map_view;
    boolean animate = false;

    public MapModel(int size, MapView map_view)
    {
        this.width = size;
        this.height = size;
        this.map_view = map_view;
    }

    public void updateMapModel (){
        map_view.repaint();
    }
    //if obstacles can't fit then method returns
    public void createRandomObstacles(int num_obstacles, int start_diameter)
    {
        this.start_diameter = start_diameter;
        obstacle_list.clear();
        ArrayList<Point> point_list = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for(int i = 0; i < num_obstacles; i++) {
            int rand_x = (int)(Math.random()*(width-start_diameter))+start_diameter;
            int rand_y = (int)(Math.random()*(height-start_diameter))+start_diameter;
            point_list.add(new Point(rand_x, rand_y));
            /*
            double min_distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            Point p1 = point_list.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < point_list.size(); j++) {
                Point p2 = point_list.get(j);
                if(j != i && p1.distance(p2) < min_distance)
                    min_distance = p1.distance(p2);
            }
            min_distance = Math.sqrt(min_distance*min_distance/2);
            int min_int = (int)(min_distance/2);
            if(min_int > 1) {
                int width = (int)(Math.random()*(min_int)); 
                width = Math.min(width, Math.max(p1.x, this.width - p1.x));
                int height = (int)(Math.random()*(min_int));
                height = Math.min(height, Math.max(p1.y, this.height - p1.y));
                if(p1.x + width > this.width - start_diameter && p1.y + height > this.height - start_diameter) {
                    width = this.width - start_diameter - p1.x; 
                    height = this.height - start_diameter - p1.y;
                }

                if(!(width < 0 && height < 0))
                    obstacle_list.add(new Obstacle(p1.x, p1.y, width, height));
            }
            */
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < num_obstacles; i++) {


            double min_distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            Point p1 = point_list.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < num_obstacles; j++) {
                Point p2 = point_list.get(j);
                if(j != i && p1.distance(p2) < min_distance)
                    min_distance = p1.distance(p2);
            }
            min_distance = Math.sqrt(min_distance*min_distance/2);
            int min_int = (int)(min_distance/2);
            if(min_int > 1) {
                int width = (int)(Math.random()*(min_int)); 
                width = Math.min(width, Math.max(p1.x, this.width - p1.x));
                int height = (int)(Math.random()*(min_int));
                height = Math.min(height, Math.max(p1.y, this.height - p1.y));
                if(p1.x + width > this.width - start_diameter && p1.y + height > this.height - start_diameter) {
                    width = this.width - start_diameter - p1.x; 
                    height = this.height - start_diameter - p1.y;
                }

                if(!(width < 0 && height < 0))
                    obstacle_list.add(new Obstacle(p1.x, p1.y, width, height));
            }
        }

        updateMapModel();
    }

    public void moveAgent() {
        if(animate) {


            double speed = Math.sqrt(width*height/10);
            Point p = subgoal_list.get(0);
            if(p.x == agent.x && p.y == agent.y) {
                if(subgoal_list.size() == 1) {
                    animate = false;
                    return;
                }
                subgoal_list.remove(0);
                p = subgoal_list.get(0);
            }

            double distance = Point.distance(agent.x, agent.y, p.x, p.y);
            double delta_x = (p.x - agent.x)/distance;
            double delta_y = (p.y - agent.y)/distance;
            double distance2 = Math.sqrt(delta_x*delta_x + delta_y+delta_y);
            if(distance2 > distance) {
                agent.x = p.x;
                agent.y = p.y;
            }
            else {
                agent.x += delta_x;
                agent.y += delta_y;
            }
            updateMapModel();
        }
        else {
            endPathfinding();
        }
    }

    public void startAnimation(int agent_diameter, boolean animate) {
        agent = new Agent(0,0,agent_diameter);
        this.animate = animate;
        timer.start();
        moveAgent();
    }

    public void startPathfinding(String algorithm, int agent_diameter, boolean animate) {

        if(algorithm.equals("A*")) {
            startAStar(agent_diameter);
            this.current_algorithm = "A*";
        }
        if(subgoal_list == null) {
            this.current_algorithm = "NONE";
        }
        startAnimation(agent_diameter, animate);
    }

    public void endPathfinding() {
        agent = null;
        subgoal_list = null;
        timer.stop();
        this.current_algorithm = "NONE";
    }

    public void startAStar(int agent_diameter) {
        grid_manager = new GridSpaceManager(obstacle_list, width, height);
        if(agent_diameter > start_diameter) return;
        agent = new Agent(agent_diameter/2, agent_diameter/2, agent_diameter);
        subgoal_list = AStar(grid_manager.getNode(0, 0), grid_manager.getNode(width - 1, height - 1));
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> AStar(SearchSpaceNode start, SearchSpaceNode goal) {
        Point start_point = start.point_list[0];
        Point goal_point = goal.point_list[0];
        PriorityQueue<SearchSpaceNode> open_set = new PriorityQueue<SearchSpaceNode>();
        ArrayList<SearchSpaceNode> closed_set = new ArrayList<SearchSpaceNode>();

        HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, SearchSpaceNode> came_from = new HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, SearchSpaceNode>();
        HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer> g_score = new HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer>();
        HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer> f_score = new HashMap<SearchSpaceNode, Integer>();

        int start_f_value = (int)manhattan_distance(start,goal);

        g_score.put(start, 0);
        f_score.put(start, start_f_value);

        start.f_value = start_f_value;
        open_set.add(start);

        while(open_set.size() > 0) {
            SearchSpaceNode current = open_set.poll();


            if(current == goal) {
                ArrayList<Point> subgoal_list = reconstructPath(came_from, current);
                subgoal_list.add(goal_point);
                return subgoal_list;
            }

            closed_set.add(current);
            ArrayList<SearchSpaceNode> neighbors = current.getNeighbors();
            for(int i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); i++) {
                SearchSpaceNode neighbor = neighbors.get(i);
                if(closed_set.contains(neighbor))
                    continue;

                int tentative_g_score = g_score.get(current) + 1;

                if(!open_set.contains(neighbor) || !g_score.containsKey(neighbor) 
                        || tentative_g_score < g_score.get(neighbor)) {
                    int tentative_f_score = tentative_g_score + (int)manhattan_distance(neighbor, goal);

                    came_from.put(neighbor, current);
                    g_score.put(neighbor, tentative_g_score);
                    f_score.put(neighbor, tentative_f_score);
                    neighbor.f_value = tentative_f_score;
                    if(!open_set.contains(neighbor))
                        open_set.add(neighbor);
                }

            }
        }



        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> reconstructPath(
            HashMap<SearchSpaceNode,SearchSpaceNode> came_from,SearchSpaceNode current_node) {
        ArrayList<Point> subgoal_list = new ArrayList<Point>();


        while(came_from.containsKey(current_node)) {
            SearchSpaceNode temp = came_from.get(current_node); 
            subgoal_list.add(0, temp.point_list[0]);
            came_from.remove(current_node);
            current_node = temp;
        }
        return subgoal_list;
    }

    public double manhattan_distance(SearchSpaceNode start, SearchSpaceNode goal) {
        Point start_point = start.point_list[0];
        Point goal_point = goal.point_list[0];
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(goal_point.x - start_point.x,2) + Math.pow(goal_point.x - start_point.x,2));
        //return Math.abs(goal_point.x - start_point.x) + Math.abs(goal_point.y - start_point.y);
    }

    public String algorithmRunning(){return current_algorithm;}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(animate) {
            moveAgent();
        }
    }
}
```